# What action to take on old accepted answer that keeps getting downvotes?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, down-votes, old-questions

Almost two years ago I answered a question with a simple link to a library which seemed to help the questioner since my answer was accepted.

My answer keeps getting downvoted but no other good answers seems to be available.

I cannot downvote or delete my own answer.

It would probably be wrong to edit the answer and remove the link since it was accepted.
I cannot really give any more value to the answer since this is certainty not my area of expertise, I was just trying to be helpful.

[This is the question I'm referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249874/creating-a-rest-client-api)

Comment: Edit your answer and tick the Community Wiki check box.

Comment: @Hans: That won't prevent downvotes... they just won't count against reputation. Better to improve the answer, IMO.

Comment: That answer is now deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your answer to explain the situation - explain that you understand it's not a good answer, and that you'd like it to be unaccepted in order to delete it.

You can edit it and still say "This is the answer that was accepted:"

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but people might disagree with adding lots of meta-discussion to an answers body.

Comment: @sth: While it's not a great idea *in general*, it helps not to be too slavish about this sort of thing. Giving a bit of extra explanation in an unusual situation is fine, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

As a lot of people are looking at the question, way not edit your answer to include the correct information from the other answers.

Or you could flag it asking the modulator to delete your answer and explain way.